# Powershell script redirecting output to text file

Tags: powershell, io-redirection, tee

My Script contains a delay , I want to display the output to Console and Store it into a file

```
Write-host "Line 1...."

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000

Write-host "Line 2...."

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000

Write-host "Line 3...."
```

When I am running the script it is not redirecting it to text file

`& script.ps1 | tee test.txt`

or

`& script.ps1 >test.txt`

both are not working.

Comment: You cannot redirect the output of `Write-Host` this way. You could simply omit the `Write-Host` and just "throw" the strings `"Line 1 ..."`and `"Line 2 ..."` and so on ... or you use `Write-Output` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Write-host "Line 1...." 2>&1 >> C:\temp\STDOUT.log

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
Write-host "Line 2...." 2>&1 >> C:\temp\STDOUT.log

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50

Write-Output "Line 1.............." 2>&1 >> C:\temp\STDOUT.log
Write-Output "Line 2 ................" 2>&1 >> C:\temp\STDOUT.log

PS C:\temp> Get-Content .\STDOUT.log
Line 1..............
Line 2 ................

Please refer   :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6